# Getting separate parts of a regex in javascript match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex in javascript. I want to match a string so its `product (,|x) quantity, each price`. The following regex does this; however it returns an array with one element only. I want an array which returns the whole matched string first followed by product, quantity, each price.

```
// product,| [x] quantity, each price:
var pQe = inputText.match(/(^[a-zA-z -]+)(?:,|[ x ]?) (\d{0,3}), (?:each) ([£]\d+[.]?\d{0,2})/g);
```

(,|x) means followed by a comma or x, so it will match `ice-cream, 99, $99` or `ice-cream x 99, $99`

How can I do that?

Comment: It turns out I had to remove the /g, I changed it to /i. Thank you everyone anyway. Can someone please remove this question as I am not registered.

Answer (score 2):

Use the exec function of the RegExp object.  For that, you'll have to change the syntax to the following:

```
 var pQe = /(^[a-z ... {0,2})/g.exec(inputText)
```

Element 1 of the returned array will contain the first element of the match, element 2 will contain the second, and so on.  If the string doesn't match the regular expression, it returns null.

Comment: There is no need to switch to using exec.  The match function that they were using also returns the array of matches.